# Example of non-flat modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, flatness

Let $R = \mathbb{C}[t]$ be a ring of polynomials in variable $t$ with coefficients in the field of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ and let $$N = R[x]/(tx-t).$$

I claim that $N$ is not a flat $R$- module. If we consider the exact sequence $$0 \rightarrow(t) \rightarrow R$$ such that the ideal $(t)$ is viewed as an $R$-module.

We know that the above sequence exact iff the map $(t) \rightarrow R$ is injective. Let us assume that N is flat then this means that $N \otimes  (t) \rightarrow N \otimes R$ has to be injective. How do I go from here?

Thanks.

Comment: One thing you could show is that since R is a PID, flat is equivalent to torsion free

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should be more precise when denoting tensor products. Actually, in your framework, $\otimes$ may mean $\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}$ or $\otimes_R$.

If $\otimes=\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}$ then you are thinking at $R$ and $N$ as $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces. Thus they are free and hence flat.

If $\otimes=\otimes_R$ then proceed as follows. Set $I:=\langle tx-t\rangle\subseteq R$. Consider the element $\left(x-1+I\right)\otimes_R t\in N\otimes_R \langle t\rangle$. Notice that since $1\notin \langle t\rangle$ we do **not** have $\left(x-1+I\right)\otimes_R t=\left(tx-t+I\right)\otimes_R 1=0$ in $N\otimes_R \langle t\rangle$. However, when you map this element to $N\otimes_R R$ via $N\otimes_R \langle t\rangle \to N\otimes_R R$ then now we have $1\in R$ and so $\left(x-1+I\right)\otimes_R t=\left(tx-t+I\right)\otimes_R 1=0$ in $R$.

Conclusion: the map is not injective and hence $N$ cannot be flat.

Comment: I apologize for the bad notation. Yes I want the tensor product  $\otimes _R$. Yes, it made a lot of sense to me. Thanks.

Comment: Surely more work needs to be done. Just because the obvious attempt at zeroing out $(x-1+I)\otimes_R t$ doesn’t work, that doesn’t mean this is a nonzero element

Comment: @FShrike: sorry, but I do not understand your comment. The element $(x-1+I) \otimes_R t$ is non-zero in $N \otimes_R \langle t \rangle$ because $R \cong \langle t \rangle$ as left $R$-modules via $p \mapsto pt$ and hence $(x-1+I) \otimes_R t = 0$ in $N \otimes_R \langle t \rangle$ if and only if $x-1+I = 0$ in $N$, if and only if $1 \in \langle t \rangle$. I mean: I do not see any "obvious attempt at zeroing out $(x−1+I) \otimes_R t$" (also because the expression $(tx-t+I) \otimes_R 1$ makes no sense in $N \otimes_R \langle t \rangle$ unless $1 \in \langle t \rangle$, which is not the case).

Comment: I am sorry if my sentence "since $1 \notin \langle t \rangle$ we do not have $(x−1+I)\otimes_R t = (tx−t+I) \otimes_R 1=0$ in $N \otimes_R ⟨t⟩$" created some confusion.

Comment: @EnderWiggins I understood the sentence you quote, I know you can’t move from $(x-1+I)\otimes_R t$ to immediately get $(tx-t+I)\otimes_R1$. What I meant was, although you explained why we can’t use tensor properties to move the $t$ across, you didn’t show that $(x-1+I)\otimes_R t\neq0$. But now that you mention it, it is clear from the general isomorphism $M\otimes_R R\cong M$.